# Stock trading script

Tags: python, finance

The script uses a financial indicator called moving averages and their crossover points to recommend best actions for stock trading (buy vs sell).

- `starting_cash`: initial cash position
- `prices`: list of prices (ordered by time)
- `crossovers`: list of crossover points on the prices, `crossovers[i]` is a list `[time_index, buy_index]`
- `buy_index` = 1 means "buy" and `buy_index` = 2 means "sell"

I'm just looking to simplify the script but can provide more context if anyone wants it.

```
def make_trades(starting_cash, prices, crossovers):

    value = [starting_cash] #set value to starting_cash
    value = []  # creating empty set?
    stock_at = 0
    cash = starting_cash

    for i in range(0,len(prices)):
        added_value = (prices[i] - prices[i-1])/prices[i-1]
        try:
            time_index = crossovers[0][0]
            buy_index = crossovers[0][1]              
            if i == time_index:            
                if buy_index == 1:
                    stock_at = cash
                    cash = 0 
                    value.append(stock_at)                                                           
                    crossovers = crossovers[1:]
                else:
                    if(stock_at == 0):
                        cash = value[i-1]
                        value.append(value[i-1])
                    else:
                        cash = value[i-1] + value[i-1]*added_value
                        stock_at = 0
                        value.append(cash)
                    crossovers = crossovers[1:]
            else:
                if cash == 0:                
                    stock_at = value[i-1] + value[i-1]*added_value
                    value.append(stock_at)
                else:
                    value.append(cash)                      
        except (IndexError):
            added_value = (prices[i] - prices[i-1])/prices[i-1]
            if cash == 0:
                stock_at = value[i-1] + value[i-1]*added_value
                value.append(stock_at)
            else:
                value.append(cash)            
    return [round(i, 2) for i in value]
```

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
for i in range(0,len(prices)):
    added_value = (prices[i] - prices[i-1])/prices[i-1]
```

You start with `i = 0`. In that case, `prices[i-1]` will be `prices[-1]` which will access the last element in the prices list. That is, `prices[len(prices) - 1]`.

I think this probably isn't what you want. You might want to do:

```
for i in range(1, len(prices)):
```

instead, so that `prices[i-1]` starts at zero. But then you won't run the loop on `i=0`, if that matters.

Alternatively, you might want to try:

```
last_price = 0
for i, price in enumerate(prices):
    added_value = 1.00 if last_price == 0 else (price - last_price)/last_price

    # ...
    last_price = price
```

**Get rid of magic numbers**

Your declaration that "buy_index == 1" means buy, and 2 means sell is ridiculous. If your code produces those numbers, then change your code. If you are reading the numbers from somewhere, change the numbers:

```
crossovers = ((t, 'buy' if a == 1 else 'sell') for t,a in crossovers)
```

You might use an enum instead, but if you're going to JSON, or reading from JSON, the string is probably easier.

**Use modern Python idioms**

One of the tenets of "modern Python" (3.x-style) is a bias towards iteration, especially the notion of infinite iterables. In other words:

1. Expect iterables, not sequences.
2. Generate, don't return a list.

I suggest that you convert `prices` to a series of (time, price) tuples, so that there is only one "source of truth" when it comes to what time should associate with a price.

Next, treat `prices` and `crossovers` as series, not lists: assume they are potentially infinite, and iterate them instead of trying to index them:

```
xo = iter(crossovers)
x_time, x_action = next(xo)

for time, price in prices:
    if time == x_time:
        if x_action == 'buy':
            #...
        x_time, x_action = next(xo)
```

Similarly, don't build a `values = []` list and return it. Instead, `yield` your values when appropriate. And since they aren't indexed in a list, provide a timestamp to go along:

```
        yield time, round(cash, 2)
        # or
        yield time, round(stock_at, 2)
```